# Virus duplicated user account on XP?

Tags: windows-xp, virus

Could a virus create duplicate accounts in Windows XP? Said duplicate accounts have same rights (admin...), same name, but the folder name under C:\Documents and Settings\ is OrignalName-CJP[RandomLetters]. If so, what virus would do that?

Further behaviour description: All account files (from My Documents, Desktop, etc) are in the -CJP folder, not the original user's folder, thus indicating that login effectively occurs in CJP account, even if the account selected in the logon screen is the original name.

Comment: It may not be a virus, it could be a temporary profile created by XP because the original user profile is corrupt. Did you scan for viruses yet?

Comment: @Moab I have, found one Trojan, but removal wasn't 100% successful. I was just wondering if that in itself could be a virus. My main symptom is somewhat unrelated, will post in another question.

Comment: When in doubt, back up important data and do a clean install of the OS.

Comment: @Moab Definitely working that angle. Thanks :)

Comment: which trojan? it might be related to the issue - since there appears to be a trojan of that name according to google

Comment: Turns out there was (also?) a malware called Sera (http://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?t=37685) on the computer.

Comment: @Moab Any further information on what this might be?  I have a similar situation, except that I also always have 0 HD space left.

Comment: @avi sounds like a virus, back up personal files and do a clean re-install of the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "RandomLetters" are probably a temporary computer name under which the accounts were created (and using the other accounts of the same name as templates).  I'm guessing that either a virus or SpyWare was attempting to set up a backdoor, or an update ran amock and this extraneous account creation was an unintended side-effect.

When an account, say "Administrator" for this example, already exists on a computer, and then you login to a network account by the same name, a local account called "Administrator.NETWORK_NAME" gets created to avoid a conflict with the local account that doesn't have that trailing computer name.

I've also noticed that accounts are sometimes created with this network or computer name added after a account of the same name was previous deleted by the data files remained.  Obviously this is caused by Windows re-creating the account in a manner that doesn't conflict with another account of the same name (especially since some files in the user's "Documents and Settings" profile directories can't be deleted).

Comment: Any idea which viruses or spyware do this sort of behavior?